# RoR DateTimePicker convert String to DateTime Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the `bootstrap3 datetimepicker`. When the user selects a date, it returns a string. I can't figure out how to change the datatype to a `datetime` object. i thought the best way to archive this task was to use the callback `before_save`.  When I implement my method i get the following error.

```
Processing by EventsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"FSSSA==", 
"event"=>{"name"=>"Omaha", "location"=>"Omaha", "date_time"=>"05/24/2017 9:04 PM"}, 
"commit"=>"Save"}
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
No template found for EventsController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 54ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Event.rb

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, :date_time, :location, presence: true
  before_save :parse_date_time
  private

  def parse_date_time
    self.date_time = DateTime.strptime(date_time, "%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p")
  end
end
```

Event view:

```
= form_for event do |f|
 .form-group
= f.label :name, 'Event Name:'
 .text
  = f.text_field  :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Add Your  Event Name Here'

 .form-group
= f.label :location
 .text
  = f.text_field :location, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Location or Venue Name'

 .form-group
= f.label :date_time
 .text
  = f.text_field :date_time, class: 'form-control', id: 'datetimepicker', placeholder: 'Date and Event Start Time'
```

= f.submit 'Save'

Controller

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

 def index
  @events = Event.all
 end

 def new
  @event = Event.new
 end

 def create
  @event = Event.new(event_params)

  if @event.save
   redirect_to @events
  end
 end

 private

 def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:name, :location, :date_time)
 end
end
```

My end goal is to convert the `string` to a `datetime` object every time a new event is created or updated. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I just tested your code with your given example - It's working just fine. So please provide more information of what's not working.

Comment: when I try save the form I get the following error.  `0.1ms)  BEGIN
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
No template found for EventsController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 54ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)`

Comment: That is because Rails does not know what to render in the end. Add something like `redirect_to root_path` as the last line of your controllers create method if the record was successfully saved. Again, it would help a lot of you would edit your question to include this error message and the controller code.

Comment: Sorry about the missing controller, I just edited the message but the error message was in the first code example.

Comment: Finally, please post your entire EventsController, along with the entire "event view". Also specify what behavior you expect if the model could be saved, as well as if it did not save (ie, where do you want the user to end up in terms of views afterwards?).

Comment: I've updated the controller and the view with the full code. I'm expecting the `event.date_time` to be saved as a `date_time` object and once save to be redirect to `@index` and if not saved to `@new`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it using `self.datetime.to_datetime`.

Example:

```
"1-1-2012".to_datetime
# => Sun, 01 Jan 2012 00:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: where? in the model?

Comment: but the params that are being returned are `05/24/2017 11:02 PM`  `05/24/2017 11:02 PM`.to_datetime` returns invalid

Answer (score 0):

Alright. The error does not seem to be your Model code, but rather the form and controller-methods. Please edit your `#create` method like so:

```
  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)

    if @event.save
      redirect_to events_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

This will attempt to create an `Event`-object with your posted params and tries to save it. If for whatever reason it's not saving, it'll render the `new.html.erb` view in which you can output all possible errors. Otherwise it'll redirect to the index-path.

Furthermore you want to edit your form-code like so:

```
= form_for @event do |f|
```

Note the `@` in front of your variable. This allows for the edit-page to use an existing object and pre-fill all its attributes into your form.

In order to display errors within your form, you can use the following code or switch to a form-helper like `Formtastic` or `SimpleForm` (I recommend the latter for simpler use, but that's completely opinion-based).

```
<% @event.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
  <li><%= message %></li>
<% end %>
```

This will display all errors accordingly.
Let me know if there's other problems you run into.

Comment: With your suggestions, nothing is saving.  I did notice in `pry` that date is not saving under `@event`   `id: nil,
 name: "p",
 location: "p",
 date_time: nil,
 workout_id: nil,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil>`
   But its in the params `[5] pry(#<EventsController>)> event_params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"p", "location"=>"p", "date_time"=>"05/27/2017 5:54 AM"} permitted: true>
[6] pry(#<EventsController>)>`